# Any year view scheduler and calendar asp.net control available there

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I searched the internet for a calendar/scheduler year view control. The UI should looks like the screenshot I gave. I will put all events  to this control.

So far, I only found:
http://web2cal.com/ajaxeventscalendar/calendar-demo/912-premium-demo/172-year-view-demo
(not very decent)
and 
the control at http://www.daypilot.org/scheduler-lite.html,which is close but not excatly I want.

I've reasearched the compenentArt,telerik, but there controls only give month/day view not a year view.

Any other recommendation? 
[image]

Comment: What was the reason for the down vote????

Comment: @Mark Kram, no idea, I just thought maybe someone else crossed the same request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

fullcanlendar might be worth a try:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

you have to define custom view somehow:
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/views/Available_Views/

Comment: Since you are the first one give the direction, I will accepct this a answer. It does give the possibility to achieve a year view, and it will involve a big big effort!!!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery fullcalendar plugin called Arshaw's fullcalendar plugin may help you achieve what you wish. you have to customize this to your needs though. Since you are using asp.net  **[Here](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar-asp-net/)** is a google code project for asp.net which will help you achieve most of the common tasks.

it basically utilizes the jquery fullcalendar plugin by arshaw [FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/). go through the documentation for better understanding and customizations

[Documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/eventRender/)

Once you configured fullcalendar successfully then i found a patch on google code which may help you

[Discussion](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=871)

[Actual Patch](http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/attachmentText?id=871&aid=8710008000&name=fullcalendar.patch&token=hdVe07wq3nWuRTm38jDSEGWO3Sg:1329927276785)

i hope this will help you and will suffice your needs. honestly i did not tried that for yearview but the patch looks promising.