# A calendar for the whole year view

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, calendar

I have the following requirement :

A calendar (wall plan) for the whole year and specifying my events from the database.

Are there any free controls which provide a year view feature?

I've searched and all I found are day, week, and month views. Even the `telerik` schedule control.

Any suggestions or recommendations please?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4724350/asp-net-availability-calendar-showing-full-year

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there isn't any full calender view control for free as far as I can see. There is a similar thread on Stackoverflow which comes to the same conclusion:

[Any year view scheduler and calendar asp.net control available there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9397964/any-year-view-scheduler-and-calendar-asp-net-control-available-there)

I recommend therefore that you take one of the thousands jquery monthly calendar controls and customize it to your needs which should be your only possibility if you don't want spend some money on a proper solution.

I guess you have already figured out some of the most interesting controls which give you a monthly view. I will post some good ones anyway:

http://www.devcurry.com/2010/06/5-jquery-calendar-plugins-that-can-be.html
http://www.queness.com/post/656/10-beautiful-jquery-and-mootool-calendar-plugins

And another version (which is not freeware) BUT there is a freeware version of it:
http://web2cal.com/ajaxeventscalendar/calendar-demo/912-premium-demo/172-year-view-demo
--> Give it a try it looks promising to me!!!

I hope this answer could help you a bit with your question.

Greetings